# How do I detect the event when tab on an input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I detect the event when tapping on an input?

I have a form where I have 5 inputs. I need to add a ccs class that changes the color of the label when the user changes from one input to another by tab

```
const InputGroup = function () {
  const greating = function (e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    console.log("only clicked");
  };
  return (
    <div className="input-group-with-icons">
      <label htmlFor="name" className="form-label">
        Name:
      </label>
      <div className="input-group">
        <span className="input-group-text iconify" id="basic-addon1" data-icon="carbon:string-text" data-width="50" data-height="50"></span>
        <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Name" aria-label="name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" name="name" onClick={greating} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
export default InputGroup;
```

I can't find a way to detect the tab event

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDbLF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event) event to detect focus in Javascript:

```
<input type="text" onfocus={focusinhandler} onfocusout={focusouthandler} />
```

If your goal is to changing styling, you can use the [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus) selector in CSS:

```
.input-group-text.iconify:focus {
    // Colour Change
}
```

which is applied when an element gains focus.

Comment: Warning: React uses onFocus and onBlur instead of onFocusIn and onFocusOut. All React events are normalized to bubble, so onFocusIn and onFocusOut are not needed/supported by React